# Trine with multiple keyboards/mice

Tags: trine

So I know you can use multiple keyboards and mice with Trine - they introduced a patch to deal with it, I heard.

So my question is this: I have two laptops, each with its own mouse, is there a way I can get the game to recognize the second laptop as just an extra mouse and keyboard?  Not LAN or online play - I know Trine doesn't do those - but treating the equipment of the second laptop as though they were simply extras plugged into the first.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

There's no hardware way to do this with two laptops, but you might be able to rig [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/) to direct the laptop that is not playing the game's input to the other laptop.  [This thread](http://groups.google.com/group/synergy-plus/browse_thread/thread/57b034301347f466) on their mailing list seems to indicate it's possible, but I've not tested it personally.